# Intellij IDEA: Pinned tabs, close will close. How to disable?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have a hotkey for closing tabs, CTRL + W but it closes even pinned tabs.

So does the [X] on the tabs.

And so does the right click -> close tab.

Is this a bug?

It didn't use to be like this.

I am on intellij 13

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a 3rd-party plugin available since 2016 that lets you disable closing pinned tabs:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8442-a-prevent-pinned-tabs-from-closing-plugin--by-momomo-com

It hides the `X` button from the tab. However you also have to manually update your key mapping:

1. Open preferences
2. select Keymap
3. search "momomo" (the plugin author)
4. select "Close Unless Pinned"
5. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> on macOS)

Now you will be prevented from closing the tab via the keyboard or mouse, unless you unpin it first.

[image: screenshot of PhpStorm settings]

Comment: Thank you. I wrote it.

Comment: Unfortunately the 2021.x update again breaks the pinned tabs feature since Intellij implemented a lesser version of pinned tab feature that forces them to the left. I hate it. So slow too to do anything with tabs now.

Comment: @mmm Ha awesome! Well thank you for the plug-in because it had been driving me nuts too. Maybe not perfect but certainly better than before

Comment: However, as I mentioned. "Latest" Intellij versions kind of break my intention of how to use the plugin. Have you noticed the change in behavior? There are tickets of complaints but are not being taken seriously. They kind of implemented their own version of pinned tabs now but since they force them to left it make organizing or moving tabs in between very difficult.

Comment: @mmm I only just installed it so I didn’t get to experience the previous behavior. I don’t mind them pinning to the left though since the only other app I pin tabs in is Firefox and they do the same thing. I can see how that change would be frustrating though!

Comment: Just started using this with PHPStorm 2023.3.4, and it's working well for me.

Answer (score 6):

Pinning a tab in IntelliJ simply means [it will not automatically close when you have exceeded the maximum number of allowed open tabs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/pinning-and-unpinning-tabs.html) (the value of which you can edit, but is 10 by default). It has nothing to do with your own actions to close it (except for the `Close All but Pinned` option in the right-click context menu on tabs).

Comment: Yes, this kind of sucks big cahones

Comment: I set maximum open tabs to 9999 because auto-closing sucks fat derrière. Nothing warned me that pinned tabs become useless when I do that. However there's a plugin in the default repository to make pinned tabs behave like in the browser: search for (sic) "A prevent pinned tabs from closing plugin - by momomo.com". Note that the plugin only works when you remap the close key.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a bug. I don't remember it being any other way, and I've used IntelliJ since the first release (I suppose that I may not have been paying attention though). Pinned windows simply stay visible when inactive, whilst unpinned windows will close automatically.

Comment: Stay visible when inactive? I don't understand what you mean. I believe it didn't use to be like this, but I could be wrong. Either way, it should behave as I suggest. Perhaps there is a plugin, I will check.

Comment: @momomo when your maximum number of editor tabs is reached, the "inactive" (read: by default, least used) tabs are closed when a new editor tab is opened. Pinned tabs will not close even if they are the least used tabs.

Comment: There is a plugin developed for this now, by us.