# What does pinning a tab do in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I've noticed you can pin a tab on any file in PhpStorm, what does it do? It seems I can just close the tab anyway.

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer, but on a related note if you want to disable closing pinned tabs, there is a 3rd-party plugin available that lets you do just that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69020242/704803

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### tl;dr: it's use to stop the file from auto closing.

1. PhpStorm can limit the number of tabs you have opened at once.
2. When it reaches it's limit it will close tab accordingly (by default this is 10 in your settings)
3. To stop selected tabs from been closed, you can pin the tabs.
4. Probably the most useful feature - When you go to right click on a tab, close all, it will not close the pinned tabs.

Summary from the PhpStorm [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/pinning-and-unpinning-tabs.html) on this.

Comment: Also, when you right click on a tab and click Close All but Pinned or Close Others, the pinned tabs will not be closed.

Comment: Well so you basically copy-pasted the manual's instructions here.  At least provide a source. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/pinning-and-unpinning-tabs.html

Comment: @MadDog Yes good point, but that doesn't work for alt click when I tested it?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes That was the wrong post, adjusted to summary now and credited :)