# Intellij: Move tab left and right

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-13

Is there a way to move/reposition a tab using the keyboard? I know I can switch tab using ALT + LEFT/RIGHT, and I would like to be able to move them maybe using ALT + SHIFT + LEFT/RIGHT.

Is this possible?

Comment: install "TabMover" on "Preferences > Plugins", it's a shame that you need to install a plug-in to accomplish this...

Comment: @7ynk3r - TabMover unfortunately doesn't work for me (currently on Ubuntu 19.10). Does it work for other people reading this?

Comment: @7ynk3r Try move tab left and right using the keyboard plugin by momomo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a plugin for this since a while back:**

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8443-a-move-tab-left-and-right-using-the-keyboard-plugin--by-momomo-com

Answer (score 14):

The plugin [TabMover](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23721) has been working for the past few years in WebStorm. (I last checked January 2019.)

You can install it directly from `Preferences > Plugins`. Just search for `TabMover`

---

On MacBooks the default keybindings are <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>

But you can remap them to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> if you want:

Under `Preferences > Keymap` search for `Move Tab To Previous` and `Move Tab To Next`

---

Incidentally, if you are a Mac user, and you want the same behaviour for tabs in Google Chrome, I can recommend the extension [Keyboard Shortcuts to Reorder Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-to-reo/moigagbiaanpboaflikhdhgdfiifdodd). Firefox works out-of-the-box!

Comment: There is a plugin for that: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8443-a-move-tab-left-and-right-using-the-keyboard-plugin--by-momomo-com

Comment: At the time of this comment, I confirm it also works on Pycharm

Answer (score 7):

There is no built-in keyboard shortcut for this functionality as of the latest 2017 build.

You can [vote for it in the issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23721) though.

Comment: There is a plugin for this, https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8443-a-move-tab-left-and-right-using-the-keyboard-plugin--by-momomo-com

Comment: This plugin is mentioned in the issue and works: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10131-tabmover (the one mentioned by mono doesn't seem to work in all jetbrains products judging by the comments)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if you can move the actual tabs. 
However if you use `CTRL + TAB` you get the same functionality you would see by doing `ALT + TAB` on Windows.

Meaning you can hold the key combination to find a tab you want to quick swap with, and then just press the key combination to switch back and forth.

Comment: Yeah, but I am thinking of organizing my tabs. Problem with Intellij is that they are always disorganized. What I would like is to also make pinned tabs unclosable but I don't think that is possible either.

Comment: @SecretService Pinning the tab will prevent IDE from closing it automatically (e.g. when limit of opened tabs is reached). There is no settings to make any tab non-closable.

Comment: @LazyOne Such a waste of a "feature"

Comment: There is a plugin for this: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8443-a-move-tab-left-and-right-using-the-keyboard-plugin--by-momomo-com

Answer (score 5):

My research suggests there's no way to do this (currently).  There is a "Move Right" and a "Move Down" but that just splits the tab groups vertically and horizontally, respectively.  There's no key binding that seems related to this, either.

Perhaps suggest it as a feature: https:// youtrack.jetbrains.net /issues/IDEA/ (they have a bad cert so I don't want to link directly)

---

There's a plugin for this that you can install: http://www.smardec.com/products/idea.html

Unfortunately, it doesn't work in Intellij 13 (gives runtime errors)

Comment: Yeah, I tried this plugin but unfortunately it seems it no longer works ( Intellij 13 ) :(

Comment: @SecretService yeah I just noticed that :T  Perhaps email the guy or modify the source (last resort)

Comment: Yeah, i will send him an email!

Comment: @momomo I so want this plugin but it doesn't work in WebStorm 2017.2

Comment: yes, i've heard. this is the shit that intellij is. there used to be great plugins and intellij was even better in 2008 but they continue to make updates and break older plugins. we'll try to look into it when we have time. we are still on 16 as of now so we see no reason to update. we'll try to do it soon though.

Comment: @FireCoding Send me an email to the plugin mail.

Answer (score 2):

My workaround for this is to set keyboard shortcuts in IntelliJ for

1. **Move to opposite group**
2. **Move right**

**What these keyboard shortcuts do:** 
*Move to opposite group:* (moves your tab to the other tab is the window is already split. Does nothing if there is no split tab.)
*Move right:* (this splits the current tab in half, and moves your current tab to the other half) So, when there are no tabs, use the keyboard shortcut for move to right, and if there is one already, use move to opposite group.

**To set keyboard shortcuts**, open settings (Ctrl + Alt + S), and go to Keymap. Just search for "move right" or "move to opposite group"

I set mine to ctrl+numpad7 and ctrl+numlock respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is an old post but in Pycharm 2018 you can create a macro to move a tab left or right and assign a keystroke combination to it. Edit>Macro>Start macro recording

Answer (score -1):

By default, it seems that Alt+Right/Alt+Left is now doing the job:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-code-editor.html

[image]

For me, I use Alt+Left / Alt+Right to navigate through locations. So I have set Alt+Ctrl+Left/Alt+Ctrl+Right to move between tabs.

[image]

Comment: This is to select the next/previous tab. The question was about moving the tab. You are going to need a plugin for that.